# Common Layout Gone with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, layout, view, storyboard

Is there any way to go back to common layout once you've gone to Swift 3? I was in the middle of a project when I upgraded to Swift 3, now all my views are messed up, no matter what device I'm working with in Storyboard. Just to be clear, all my constraints stayed right (when running on the simulator), but inside of the storyboard I can't seem to update the views based on constraints and cannot find how to go back to a "Common View" as was the case in earlier versions (Auto Layout).

Comment: In storyboard select your initial view controller and look at Attributes inspector (or Identity inspector, not sure about the name). On top you can see Simulated metrics. Set Size as Freeform. Then move to the next pane (Size inspector) and set width and heigh as it was before the updating to Swift 3. I guess it was 600 x 600. All other view controllers can infere this size (as long as the default size is set - Inferred).

Comment: @Andrej thank you, worked like a charm!